# Is there a client for InfluxDB similar to PgAdmin4 for Postgres

Tags: python, database, influxdb

Hi is any one aware of any clients for InfluxDB so that I can visualize the tables inside an influx database. And do that database manipulations using the visual tool.

Comment: I find a windows application in order that: [InfluxDBStudio](https://github.com/CymaticLabs/InfluxDBStudio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was [an admin interface](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/tools/web_admin/) in versions < 1.2. Since 1.3 it was removed from InfluxDB itself and moved to Chronograf.

[More info is here.](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.3/guides/transition-web-admin-interface/)