# Influxdb [admin] section doesn't exist in influxdb.conf file

Tags: windows, influxdb

I am trying to install influxdb in my Windows server 2016 for monitoring SQL server.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606715/how-to-install-influxdb-on-windows-os-and-access-admin-console) post when i was having issues getting the thing done.

In the above post it says to uncomment the [admin] part,but when i unzip the latest influxdb download from

https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-1.6.0_windows_amd64.zip 
it doesn't have that [admin] part in the influxdb.config file.

i searched for `[admin]` in the config file also searched for `8083` port in the config file.But i couldn't.

Has anything changed recently in influxdb for windows?

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387093/is-there-a-client-for-influxdb-similar-to-pgadmin4-for-postgres/49407467#49407467 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, web admin interface is no longer available from version 1.3. It has been replaced by `Chronograf`. You can read it [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/tools/web_admin/).

> As of version 1.3, the web admin interface is no longer available in
>   InfluxDB. The interface does not run on port 8083 and InfluxDB ignores
>   the [admin] section in the configuration file if that section is
>   present. Chronograf replaces the web admin interface with improved
>   tooling for querying data, writing data, and database management. See
>   Chronograf’s transition guide for more information.

Comment: So do i have to use chronograf instead of grafana? ir should i get an older version prior to 1.3 and use?

Answer (score 1):

Admin UI was deprecated in v1.2 and removed in v1.3. I believe it was done for a good reason and Chronograf suites way batter for that purpose. On the other hand, Grafana (which you are using right now) currently is the best metrics visualizer application, as far as I'm concerned, and is way more mature and rapidly developed in comparison to Chronograf (which is still good, but not as good).

Starting from ~1.4.3 version there were some descent changes made in InfluxDB and it is going to evolve further. I don't think it's worth binding yourself to an obsolete version just to have Admin UI feature out of box.

If you really want Admin UI you can do the following: use Grafana as primary metrics visualization front-end and Chronograf for managing InfluxDB and Kapacitor (in case you're going to use it). Grafana and Chronograf are not heavy services, so this setup shouldn't be demanding in terms of computational resource requirements.